# Sketch 3 exported png size different from layer

Tags: export, png, sketch-app

I'm having an issue exporting some icons from sketch to `.png` files.

The layers is are 144 x 144 but when I try exporting them I get a 152 x 152 size `.png` file.

I have enabled the <kbd>trim transparent pixels</kbd> option but nothing is changed.

Thank you for your help

Comment: What is size of your canvas? 144 or 152?

Comment: 144. I found a workaround to this. Simply i set a size of 136x136 of the icon, and that will be exported as a 144x144

Comment: what software you use?

Comment: I'm using sketch 3, as the title say

Comment: I see. This is why it sounds to me (PS user) quite surprisingly :)

Comment: There are several issue with sketch 3 exporting tool. It's now useless. Hoping in a patch in the next days, because i can't go further with my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the Slice tool or just selecting the layer and exporting it? I found myself that just exporting the layer is bugged and does what you describe. While the Slice tool works.